# Text input not showing in Kivy launcher (Android) QPython

Tags: android, python, kivy

Not sure why text input doesn't show.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = BoxLayout()
        l = Label(text="Hi there, Welcome.")
        b.add_widget(l)

        return b

textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

A short [recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTTHS.jpg).

(I'm getting this "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" but I don't have anything else to say - someone please just remove this, thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is-

```
from kivy import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
         self.box = BoxLayout()
         self.label = Label(text="Hi there, Welcome.")
         self.txt = TextInput(text='Hello world')
         self.box.add_widget(self.label)
         self.box.add_widget(self.txt)
         return self.box

 if __name__ == "__main__":
      MyApp().run()
```

Basically what you're missing out is that you need to add the text input as a widget to the add, just like you're adding the label.

Hope this helps. :)